# Firebase Cloud Messaging Refresh Token

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using this [Cordova plugin for Firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase) in FCM for my PhoneGap project, but I got no idea how I can implement the login, sign up, and log out so that I can send a push notification to a specific username when the user logs-in.

My idea is when the user logs-in, it will generate a new token and store the new token with the username in MySQL database and on user logout, it will update new token. But in the documentation, there is no way to refresh the token by using JavaScript. Thanks.